ImageList LoadPicture from SharePoint
I´m trying to load a picture from a Sharepoint to an ImageList.
When trying a local Filepath it works just fine. But trying a Filepath from a Sharepoint doesnt seem to work.
I got the same Filepath for workbooks in the Sharepoint. Those are being opened when running the Macro.
Local:
ImageList1.ListImages.Add , "1", "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\XXX\Picture.png" (works for both files and pictures)

Sharepoint
ImageList1.ListImages.Add , "1", "https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/Picture.png"  (works for Workbooks, doesnt work for pictures)

I get the Error "Path/File access error"

You'd need to download a local copy of any image with a HTTP path.
